# Non-color data (and other) option missing

Tags: node-editor, normal-map

In Image Texture node I don't have any other options but sRGB and Linear.
How do I enable the Non-Color Data option in the dropdown menu?
I followed the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1px5mPdN4s) and the guy has it, whilst I don't. Switching to cycles did not help. I use Eevee btw.
Thank you, cheers

Comment: save your texture first!

Comment: What do you mean? I import it with image texture node, it's already on my computer

Comment: What kind of image texture are you using? Png, jpg etc.

Comment: jpg and tif. One node is a gloss map another one is normal, jpg and tif.
The guy in the tutorial also has jpg and tif files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this option now shows up (at least in 2.83) after you open the image, under the "Color Space" dropdown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I searched a lot for a solution, I had a laptop that appear the all options, but on a PC it does not appear after a long search,
I found that downloading the blender from the official website does not have options, but I tried to download it from the Microsoft Store and it solved the problem, I hope the solution works for you